# Why can't I get the value of input element

Tags: javascript

I had this javascript code. But the code doesnt get the value of the input, what am i doing wrong here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunc() {
    "use strict";
    var un = document.getElementByID('user').value;
    var pw = document.getElementByID('pass').value;
    var x  ;
    if(un=="abc") {
        if(pw=="123") {
            document.getElementById('validate').innerHTML ="validation sucessful";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('validate').innerHTML ="validation unsuccessful";
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('validate').innerHTML ="invalid username";
    }
}
</script>
<p>Click on the button to login</p>

USERNAME : <input type='text'   id='user'   value="  "   /><!-- Should be like type="text" and not type="  text"-->
PASSWORD:   <input type='password'    id='pass'   />  <!-- Should be like type="password" and not type="  password"-->
<p id='validate'></p>
<input type='button'  onclick="myFunc()" value='Login' />
```

Comment: Are you really planning to check in javascript the user and password ? Are you aware that even non programmers today are able to have a look at the source (and my wife can even debug) ?

Comment: You've already gotten some answers, but a tip for future questions: Include *what* is wrong. We're not mindreaders, even if we have to get damned close some times. =)

Comment: Chris, my code wasn't doing anything  and I wanted to know why ....Well dystroy , I am just learning the basics and am not going to implement this anywhere ;) ... Sure Steen , I will take that tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its `document.getElementById` not `document.getElementByID` javascript is **Javascript is case sensitive**

```
var un = document.getElementById('user').value;
var pw = document.getElementById('pass').value;
```

not

```
var un = document.getElementByID('user').value;
var pw = document.getElementByID('pass').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect function name `getElementByID`, use this:

```
var un = document.getElementById('user').value;
var pw = document.getElementById('pass').value;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Javascript is so sensitive !!

Comment: @user1598915 Learn to live with it. You're not going to find many proper languages that aren't sensitive to case.